# Чтение файла при помощи интерфейса SeekableIterator

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток, не имел опыта работы с данных итератором.
Пытаюсь разобраться.
К примеру есть текстовый файл определённого размера.
Мне нужен класс для его чтения при помощи интерфейса SeekableIterator.
Элементом списка считать одну строку текстового файла (оканчиваются \n).

Comment: Вы забыли написать собственно вопрос. Интерфейс как интерфейс. Какую логику для него напишете -- так и будет себя вести.

Comment: На данном этапе хотелось понять синтаксис, к примеру огромный текстовый файл разложить на список, в котором строку текстового файла считать элементом списка оканчивающуюся на \n